# Twitter Retweet

Tags: python, twitter

How do I get this code to change from individual scan to scan all of twitter for to find tweets with more than 300,000 retweets.

```
import twitter
t = twitter.Api(...)
statuses = t.GetUserTimeline('username', include_rts=True)

for tweet in statuses:
    retweets = t.GetRetweets(tweet.GetId())
    users = [retweet.GetUser().GetScreenName() for retweet in retweets]
    print tweet.GetId(), users
    print tweet.GetRetweets()
```

Comment: Are you looking for retweets of a specific tweet, or just the last 300K retweets?

Comment: All tweets with over 300K retweet

Comment: Based on a hunt through the Twitter API, I don't think this is possible. All API calls relate to an individual timeline unfortunately

Comment: Is it possible to have it repeat through multiple timelines?

Comment: Sure. All you would have to do would be to create a list of users, then loop through their individual timelines doing the search for retweets as above

Answer (score 0):

its possible through sites like tweetdeck,  their API must have the code you'd need,  [tweetdeck search screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUPTf.png) in there you can set the search for any number of retweets, likes, or replies and in any combination of the three forms.  If you were looking for the ability to do such a search in the command module I'd start looking there.  Unfortunately that's as far as my expertise goes in the matter,  good luck!